# Multiple data sets in a single LineChartView

Tags: android, graph

I started using [HelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android) library and found some difficulties with adding two sets of data into my LineChartView. This is how I'm doing it:

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_details, container, false);
        performanceChart = (LineChartView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.performanceChart);
        performanceChart.setInteractive(false);
        addScoreEntriesToChart();
        addRankEntriesToChart();

        return rootView;
    }


    private void addScoreEntriesToChart() {
        List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<PointValue>();
        ArrayList<Double> latestScores = currentPlayer.getLatestScores();
        for(int i = 0; i < latestScores.size(); i++){
            values.add(new PointValue(i+1, Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(latestScores.get(i)))));
        }
        performanceChart.setLineChartData(getLineSettings(values, Color.parseColor("#0036D9")));

    }

    private void addRankEntriesToChart() {
        List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<PointValue>();
        ArrayList<Integer> latestRanks = currentPlayer.getLatestRanks();
        for(int i = 0; i < latestRanks.size(); i++){
            values.add(new PointValue(i+1, Float.valueOf(latestRanks.get(i))));
        }
        performanceChart.setLineChartData(getLineSettings(values, Color.parseColor("#84BE67")));
    }

    @NonNull
    private LineChartData getLineSettings(List<PointValue> values, int lineColor) {
        Line line = new Line(values).setColor(lineColor).setCubic(true);
        line.setStrokeWidth(2);
        line.setPointRadius(0);
        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        lines.add(line);

        LineChartData data = new LineChartData();
        data.setLines(lines);
        return data;
    }
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong because i end up seeing only one line on the LineChartView (RankEntries - the last one added).
Trying to Google the issue didn't get me the answer.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add 2 data to your chart. You must add two lines to your data, then set that data to your chart:

```
List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<PointValue>();
    ArrayList<Double> latestScores = currentPlayer.getLatestScores();
    for(int i = 0; i < latestScores.size(); i++){
        values.add(new PointValue(i+1, Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(latestScores.get(i)))));
    }

 List<PointValue> values2 = new ArrayList<PointValue>();
    ArrayList<Integer> latestRanks = currentPlayer.getLatestRanks();
    for(int i = 0; i < latestRanks.size(); i++){
        values2.add(new PointValue(i+1, Float.valueOf(latestRanks.get(i))));
    }
```

and after that:

```
Line line = new Line(values).setColor(Color.RED);
Line line2 = new Line(values2).setColor(Color.BLUE);
List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
lines.add(line);
lines.add(line2);
```